# IntelliJ debug gradle build with local tomcat server

Tags: debugging, tomcat, intellij-idea, gradle

I have a gradle project that builds a few wars that I deploy to a tomcat server. I'm trying to debug this app with intellij. I can do this by deploying the wars to an external server and using intellij to connect to that.

I was wondering if there is a way to do this using intellij's local tomcat server. When I try to create a local configuration, it asks me which artifacts I want to deploy, and I'd like to just deploy those artifacts based on my gradle configuration. Is that possible? Or should I be using the remote configuration for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with version 13 it is possible to import `Gradle` project [directly](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/importing-project-from-gradle-model.html) from Idea. With `Idea Ultimate Edition` there are also created corresponding artifacts (based on the war plugin). They can be used to deploy it on the local `Tomcat` instance just like any other artifacts and debug (works fine in my projects).

If you prefer to debug the application run and debug via [gradle-tomcat-plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-tomcat-plugin) it should be possible in Idea 13.0.2 - currently in EAP (see [IDEA-117792](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-117792), but I didn't test it).

Comment: Thanks, I'm currently using IntelliJ 12 which does let you import a gradle project directly, but I didn't see a way to create an artifact from the war plugin tasks. Is that a new feature in 13?

Comment: Answer to my own question about being new in 13 - http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/12/intellij-idea-13-is-released-work-miracles-in-java-and-beyond/ looks like it is.

Comment: If you stuck with 12 you can try [idea-utils-plugin](https://github.com/rodionmoiseev/gradle-plugins/tree/master/idea-utils-plugin). It allows to define more things when ising idea plugin for Gradle and based on [my feature request](https://github.com/rodionmoiseev/gradle-plugins/issues/6) maybe you will be able to generate (by hand, but scriptable) proper entries in Idea configuration from Gradle.